# Passing data to rickshaw with php

Tags: php, json, rickshaw

I'm having trouble integrating my data into a rickshaw graph.

I'm getting the values from a database via php, then converting the output to a json array.

Json String:

```
[{"x":"1431002979","y":"1079.547"},{"x":"1431007200","y":"1079.5468"},{"x":"1431010800","y":"1079.5469"},{"x":"1431014400","y":"1079.5469"},{"x":"1431018000","y":"1079.5472"},{"x":"1431021600","y":"1079.5473"},{"x":"1431025200","y":"1079.5475"},{"x":"1431028800","y":"1079.5478"},{"x":"1431032400","y":"1079.5479"}]
```

I then parse it to JSON with this:

```
var data=JSON.parse('<?php  echo json_encode($data); ?>');
```

If i try to load this data i get the folling error

```
uncaught exception: x and y properties of points should be numbers instead of undefined and undefined
```

so I figured there would be s.th wrong with my data type and did this

```
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    data[i]=[parseInt(data[i]['x']),parseFloat(data[i]['y'])];
}
```

I still get the same error though.

This is the code for the graph:

```
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
        element: document.querySelector("#chart"),
        width: 580,
        height: 250,
        series: [ {
            data: data,
            color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)'
        } ]
} );

graph.render();
```

greetings
David

Answer (score 0):

Try this with only

```html
<?php  echo json_encode($data,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)); ?>
```

```html
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
        element: document.querySelector("#chart"),
        width: 580,
        height: 250,
        series: [ {
            
            color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)',
            data:  <?php  echo json_encode($data,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)); ?>
        } ]
} );

graph.render();
```

Comment: `uncaught exception: x and y properties of points should be numbers instead of string and string`
strange though, this shouldnt be strings

Comment: check this .<?php echo json_encode($data,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>

Comment: this leaves me without an error, but i get a solid rectangle as a resulting graph :-)

Comment: I think it is because of your y coordinates have variations of floating points. don't u think so.try with it another values and let me know.

Comment: That should not be a Problem in my opinion. That said I need the graph to display various float numbers or it´s useless to me

Comment: most probably its because of they are two close with each other. therefore a slight difference in graph. 1079.547 ,1079.5468 ,1079.5469 are only variate in their 3rd floating point.